# Need help at redirect regex 301

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i've moved an old site to wordpress and now i need to redirect the old links to new one

**The old url**

*mysite.com/2010-11-02-11-05-12/category-old/subcategory/123-article*

Here are my redirects:

**to category page (working)**

```
RedirectPermanent /2010-11-02-11-05-12/category-old/ /archive/category-new/
```

**to article page (not working)**

```
RedirectPermanent /2010-11-02-11-05-12/(.+?)/^[0-9]+-(.+?)/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

**redirect url (404)**
*mysite.com/archive/tag/subcategory/123-article*

**the url should look like this** (the number before are removed *123-*):

*mysite.com/article*

could anyone help?

Comment: RedirectPermanent directive doesnt support regex and that is why the redirect failed. Try RedirectMatch instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectRule 2010-11-02-11-05-12/(.+?)/[0-9]+-(.+?)/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which seems to be what you were trying to use. I removed the opening forward slash as they are not included in a match from `.htaccess`. I removed the caret (^) from before the numbers as that would stop it matching. Let me know any problems.